# Ruby: записать в хэш китайские иероглифы

Tags: ruby

Нужно записать в хэш строку: First Name = 志东
так, чтобы выводилось: 志东.
Сейчас, например, у меня выводится : \xE5\xBF\x97\xE4\xB8\x9C

Comment: ...выводится **где**?

Comment: .....в терминале

Comment: А что у вас за терминал такой?

Comment: Gnome, но проблема мне кажется не в нём, потому как, если выводить строки с иероглифами, то всё в порядке. А вот после записи в хеш, вывод становится неправильным

Comment: Приложите пример, на котором это воспроизводится. У меня эта строка прекрасно выводится что сама по себе, что в составе других структур данных.

Comment: И приложите значение `Encoding.default_external`.